# Spring Security & Websockets - Authentication not set for frame handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

Given the below configuration, the initial websocket handshake to `"/connect"` succeeds with basic auth. However, I get the following exception when I send a frame through the active websocket: `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`.

I don't get the exception when I remove the `@PreAuthorize` annotation from `"/sendMessage"` in `WebsocketController`. Spring documentation says the `Authentication` from the initial HTTP handshake should be set in the SecurityContext for future websocket frames, yet this does not appear to be happening automatically.

How should I go about setting the `Authentication` for the websocket connection?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/outbound");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connect").withSockJS();
    }
}

//...............

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
        ;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
        authBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}

//.............

@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    // This fails despite successful websocket handshake
    @MessageMapping("/sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/outbound/message")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public Message message(@Payload Message message) {
        return "web socket message";
    }

    // This HTTP call succeeds
    @RequestMapping("/httpEndpoint")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public @ResponseBody String doSomething(){
        return "some response";
    }

}

// ..................

@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // all are valid
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebSockets doesn't appear to support SpringSecurity annotations so security must instead be configured with:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated()
                .simpDestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot version 1.5.10 with spring security version 4.2.4 able to use @PreAuthorize without problem.